# How to export subset of data from mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, export, bson

I currently have a large database, and I need a means of backing up subsets of the data that can then be imported on another mongodb instance.

For example, I would need to find all documents that contain a key, so essentially: find({key: 'somekey'}), and then export that data set. I thought to simply run the query in NodeJS, and save the data in JSON format. I don't think this is optimal as through my understanding simply importing the JSON data again (if needed in the future) won't be a straightforward task as the data-types will be lost.

So my question is, how would I go about exporting a subset of the dataset so that it may be possibly re-imported into another mongodb instance on another server.

Comment: You can try `mongoexport -d databasename -c collectionnaame -q  '{ key: 'somekey' }' --out /collection.json` More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump

Comment: I must have glazed right over that in the documentation. I will try it now and report back.

Comment: Worked as expected. Tested on some parts of my database, seemed to work as expected once re-imported. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Veeram's comment, the way to do this is as BSON so that it retains all the data structure:

```
sudo mongodump -d DB_Name -c Collection -q '{"key_name": "value"}' --out /home/collection
```

Then to import it back:

```
sudo mongorestore -d DB_Name -c Collection  /home/collection/DB_Name/Collection.bson
```